# State Change Not Rerendering Component Conceptual Question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

I have the following Javascript Code

```js
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isVisible: false};
    }
    render() {
        console.log('hi')
        return(
            <div className = 'navbar'>
                <div className = 'nav-button'
                    onClick = {() => this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible})}>
                </div>
           
                    <div className = 'navbar-content row'>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1 offset-s6"><h5 className="center-align">Home</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">About</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">Home</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">About</h5></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click the "nav-button", I should call setState to change the isVisible component, thus the component should re-render and I should expect the console to log 'hi'. However, this is not happening. I am wondering why the component is not re-rendering.

However, when I remove the div tag just below nav bar, the component successfully re-renders.

```js
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isVisible: false};
    }
    render() {
        console.log('hi')
        return(
            <div className = 'navbar'>
                <div className = 'nav-button'
                    onClick = {() => this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible})}>
                </div>
           
     
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.isVisible` is `undefined`. It should be `this.state.isVisible`.

Comment: Apologies -Thank you for point that out. I'm unfortunately getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you clicking the `div` if it has no contents? I believe you are mistaken that you are ever triggering the `onClick` in the first place. Below you can see a simplified running example of how this does in-fact work (The clickable `div` now has a label "test").

```js
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isVisible: false};
    }
    render() {
        console.log('hi')
        return(
            <div className = 'navbar'>
                <div className = 'nav-button'
                    onClick = {() => this.setState({isVisible: !this.isVisible})}>test
                </div>
                    <div className = 'navbar-content row'>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1 offset-s6"><h5 className="center-align">Home</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">About</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">Home</h5></div>
                        <div className="navbar-item col s1"><h5 className="center-align">About</h5></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I have width and height to my navbar-button component, so I believe the nav-bar component has content.

Comment: How are you verifying that it was actually clicked? And that the problem is with `setState`?

Comment: For instance, if you change the `div` to contain `onClick = {() => console.log('clicked')}` do you see the log?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that now. Could you also link the javscript file you wrote to generate the code snippet in your answer? I see that it is working.

Comment: There's nothing to link to, I wrote it all within the answer itself

Comment: No, the console does not register the click. However, when I remove the div tag with class ''navbar-content row' and its children elements, the click does register.

Comment: Yes, so the issue is that you are not actually clicking the div. Maybe your styles are putting another `div` over top of it? Or maybe you are simply not click the right place. I'm not sure, but the issue is not with `setState`.

Comment: Thank you. It is likely a problem with my styling. Do I close out the question or leave it? Thank you again.

Comment: As a follow up, I realized that the below div with ''navbar-content row" was overlaying the div nav-button. Setting the z-index for nav-button to 2 and navbar-content row to 1 solved the problem. However, I do not know if this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [functional form](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) of `setState` if your new state depends on the previous state:

```js
...
onClick = {() => this.setState((prevState) => ({isVisible: !prevState.isVisible}))}
...
```

Comment: That may be a recommended practice, but it has nothing to do with the current problem.